How can my web api decrypt a password, that was prevously encrypted in a console application, using DPAPI?
I have to store user credentials in a web api somewhere. I decided I create a console application in the solution, next to the Web API, that encrypts the data, and writes it to the web api's appsettings.json.
Here is the relevant code:
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddDataProtection(o =>
{
    o.ApplicationDiscriminator = CoreVariables.SALT;
}
).SetApplicationName("test");

var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

var dataProtector = services.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
var protector = dataProtector.CreateProtector(CoreVariables.DATA_PROTECTION_REASON);

//Fill username and password, REMOVE AFTER ENCRYPTION, DONT PUSH IT TO REPOSITORY
string username = "";
string password = "";

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
{
    throw new Exception("Username cannot be null or empty.");
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
{
    throw new Exception("Username cannot be null or empty.");
}

string protectedUsername = protector.Protect(username);
string protectedPassword = protector.Protect(password);

string appsettingsFilePath =
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName,
        "My.API", "appsettings.json");

if (!File.Exists(appsettingsFilePath))
{
    throw new Exception($"Cannot find file in path: {appsettingsFilePath}");
}

var appsettingsContent = File.ReadAllText(appsettingsFilePath);
var appsettingsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(appsettingsContent);
appsettingsJson["User"] = protectedUsername;
appsettingsJson["Secret"] = protectedPassword;
appsettingsJson["SecretLastChanged"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
var updatedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appsettingsJson, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(appsettingsFilePath, updatedJson);

Then, when I deploy the application, I got an exception, saying The key was not found in the key ring.
Here is the relevant code from the API:
Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDataProtection(o => {
        o.ApplicationDiscriminator = CoreVariables.SALT;
        
    }
).SetApplicationName("test");

Service, where I use it:
 public MyService(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
 {
     _protector = provider.CreateProtector(CoreVariables.DATA_PROTECTION_REASON);
 }

 public async Task<string> Authentication(string userName, string password)
 {
     string authUsername = _protector.Unprotect(userName);
     string authPassword = _protector.Unprotect(password);
 }

Does this encryption is somehow connected to computer data? When I deploy the application into a server, the decryption will not work.

Your sample does not indicate what implementation of IDataProtectionProvider is used, but many providers are either just for protection during the life time of the process. ASP.NET data protection traditionally use a machine key, i.e. a key tied to the machine, or even the user in some cases. So, yes, the encryption may well be tied to the computer, or even the user process depending on what implementation is used. Notably... Your code does not reference any kind of key material for the encryption. However it's done, you need to ensure that the encryption and decryption use the same key!

it's sort of the whole point of DPAPI.  The key is tied to the machine and/or user account.  This keeps the encrypted value fairly secure since you'll need to decrypt the value from the same machine/user that encrypted it.  If you need a persistent key, you probably won't want to be using a keyring either.

You might want to check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/dangerous-unprotect?view=aspnetcore-8.0

By default, the key is saving in the computer system directory. You could add following configuration to specify the key file path. (xxxx.xml)
serviceCollection.AddDataProtection(o =>
{
    o.ApplicationDiscriminator = CoreVariables.SALT;
}
).SetApplicationName("test").PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory));

Then when run the console application, you will find a key file is generated in this path. It contains the key information.


But every time you run the console app. It will generate a new key (also a new xxx.xml file) for use. So after you have this file. We can disable generating new keys to make it always using the old key:
...
SetApplicationName("test").PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory))
.DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration();

Then you could copy this file to the "api computer" and use the same setting to specify using this key file. (also disable keygeneration)
